# Using a select box to trigger JS event to make another select box become passive/active? HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, select, visibility, onchange

I want select box B to become visible when option 2 is selected in select box A, otherwise it should remain hidden.  It's not working.  Here's my code: [EDIT: I actually want it to be passive instead of hidden.]

The JavaScript first:

```
function toggle2(value){
if(value=='confirm')
 document.getElementById('test').style.visibility='visible';
else
 document.getElementById('test').style.visibility='hidden';
}




 <select class="select3" name="CaseType" onchange="toggle2()">
  <option value="select" selected="selected">- Select Case Type -</option>
  <option value="suspect">Suspected</option>
  <option value="confirm">Confirmed</option>
  </select>

  <select id="test" class="select4" name="test" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <option selected="selected">- Select test -</option>
  </select>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a simple attribute mix-up. That second select box has an id of `icd`, but you're trying to change it with `document.getElementById('test')`.

**EDIT**: Another problem is that you're not sending any variable to `toggle2`, so the if-then will always fail, and it will always set the visibility to hidden. I think.

Comment: I just changed those for this question.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
document.getElementById('test').style.display='none';
```

to hide element and

```
document.getElementById('test').style.display='';
```

to show it again

and by the way, when accessing element with getElementById('test'), element must contain id attribute that equals 'test'

```
<select id="test" class="select4" name="test" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

Comment: i think doing `display = 'block'` would be better than an empty string

Comment: in this way it's better to remember previous value of display. it might be not only 'block'

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty `<div>` with an id, and onchange, set the innerHTML to whatever you want.

Nur

Answer (score 0):

Here's some amended code

```
function toggle2(incontrol){
   var value=incontrol.options[incontrol.selectedIndex).value;
   if(value=='confirm'){
    document.getElementById('test').style.visibility='visible';
   }
   else{
    document.getElementById('test').style.visibility='hidden';
  }
}

 <select class="select3" name="CaseType" onchange="toggle2(this)">
  <option value="select" selected="selected">- Select Case Type -</option>
  <option value="suspect">Suspected</option>
  <option value="confirm">Confirmed</option>
  </select>

  <select id="test" class="select4" name="test" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <option selected="selected">- Select test -</option>
  </select>
```